# Subscribing to Meteor.Users Collection

Tags: mongodb, meteor

```
// in server.js
Meteor.publish("directory", function () {
return Meteor.users.find({}, {fields: {emails: 1, profile: 1}});
});

// in client.js
Meteor.subscribe("directory");
```

I want to now get the directory listings queried from the client like `directory.findOne()` from the browser's console. //Testing purposes

Doing `directory=Meteor.subscribe('directory')`/`directory=Meteor.Collection('directory')` and performing `directory.findOne()` doesn't work but when I do `directory=new Meteor.Collection('directory')` it works and returns undefined and I bet it CREATES a mongo collection on the server which I don't like because USER collection already exists and it points to a new Collection rather than the USER collection.

NOTE: I don't wanna mess with how Meteor.users collection handles its function... I just want to retrieve some specific data from it using a different handle that will only return the specified fields and not to override its default function...

Ex:

```
Meteor.users.findOne() // will return the currentLoggedIn users data
directory.findOne() // will return different fields taken from Meteor.users collection.
```

Comment: This should be `directory = new Meteor.Collection('directory')`. If it's undefined then you're probably assigning to this variable somewhere else.

Comment: I want to fetch data from the Meteor.users Collection using the "directory" as the handle, if I do new Meteor.Collection("directory") wouldn't that create a mongo collection to the server side and attach the 'directory' handle to the 'directory collection'?

Comment: Tried to put the new Meteor.Collection('directory') to the client only folder ( before it is both read by the server and client ) but still didn't work.

Comment: Ahh ... now I see what you did there :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want this setup to work, you need to do the following:

```
Meteor.publish('thisNameDoesNotMatter', function () {
  var self = this;
  var handle = Meteor.users.find({}, {
    fields: {emails: 1, profile: 1}
  }).observeChanges({
    added: function (id, fields) {
      self.added('thisNameMatters', id, fields);
    },
    changed: function (id, fields) {
      self.changed('thisNameMatters', id, fields);
    },
    removed: function (id) {
      self.removed('thisNameMatters', id);
    }
  });

  self.ready();

  self.onStop(function () {
    handle.stop();
  });

});
```

No on the client side you need to define a client-side-only collection:

```
directories = new Meteor.Collection('thisNameMatters');
```

and subscribe to the corresponding data set:

```
Meteor.subscribe('thisNameDoesNotMatter');
```

This should work now. Let me know if you think this explanation is not clear enough.

**EDIT**

Here, the `self.added/changed/removed` methods act more or less as an event dispatcher. Briefly speaking they give instructions to every client who called

```
Meteor.subscribe('thisNameDoesNotMatter');
```

about the updates that should be applied on the client's collection named `thisNameMatters` assuming that this collection exists. The name - passed as the first parameter - can be chosen almost arbitrarily, but if there's no corresponding collection on the client side all the updates will be ignored. Note that this collection can be client-side-only, so it does not necessarily have to correspond to a "real" collection in your database.

Returning a cursor from your `publish` method it's only a shortcut for the above code, with the only difference that the name of an actual collection is used instead of our `theNameMatters`. This mechanism actually allows you to create as many "mirrors" of your datasets as you wish. In some situations this might be quite useful. The only problem is that these "collections" will be read-only (which totally make sense BTW) because if they're not defined on the server the corresponding `insert/update/remove' methods do not exist.

Comment: I'll try it tomorrow :)

Comment: It works! and can you please explain to me what's really happening here :D

Comment: It's all in the [meteor's documentation here](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_publish) ;)

Comment: Saw that but a little confusion using "this" and self.foo('thisNameDoesMatter').

Comment: @o2kevin I added some more explanation. Hope this will be useful.

Answer (score 8):

The collection is called [`Meteor.users`](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_users) and there is no need to declare a new one on neither the server nor the client.

Your publish/subscribe code is correct:

```
// in server.js
Meteor.publish("directory", function () {
return Meteor.users.find({}, {fields: {emails: 1, profile: 1}});
});

// in client.js
Meteor.subscribe("directory");
```

To access documents in the users collection that have been published by the server you need to do something like this:

```
var usersArray = Meteor.users.find().fetch();
```

or

```
var oneUser = Meteor.users.findOne();
```

Comment: Okay so you're saying that if I modified the way Meteor publish the users collection even If giving it a handle like 'directory' will override the default Meteor.user call on the client?

Comment: Yes. Your explanation is a bit imprecise though. There is no call overridden on the client and 'directory' is not a subscription handle. 'directory' is the name of a record set which simply defines which documents (and fields) of the 'Meteor.users' collection are being sent to the client. The client stores those documents in a local collection with the same name as the one of the collection being used in the call to 'Meteor.publish' (i.e. 'Meteor.users').

Comment: This might override default users local collection